# ns found the right version of tclsh in /usr/bin/tclsh8.6 but it doesn't seem to be there anymore for ns2

Tags: networking, ns2

When I write $ns in Linux terminal it shows this message:

```
"When configured, ns found the right version of tclsh in /usr/bin/tclsh8.6
but it doesn't seem to be there anymore, so ns will fall back on running the first tclsh in your path. The wrong version of tclsh may break the test suites. Reconfigure and rebuild ns if this is a problem. "
```

will it cause any problem with my TCL file being executed?
I am using `ns-allinone-2.35`.

Comment: When building ns-allinone-2.35, it's preferred to use the internal {tcl, tk, otcl, tclcl}, which isn't changed by a general OS package update. I.e. the internal version will always be the right version. ... Suggest : Remove the OS development version of tcl-tk (tcl-dev, tk-dev), and rebuild ns-allinone-2.35 with the internal tcl-tk versions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For me this problem solved by upgrade tclsh.

```
sudo apt install tclsh
```

My Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTgm0UUtkxY)
basically, type the command

```
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev tk-dev
```

and it will work fine
after the installation is complete, type

```
ns
```

and then the next line will be `%`

Answer (score 0):

In my networking course, I had to learn NS2 related things. Our Teacher told us to modify TCP.cc files and other things related to that. 
If this shows in your terminal, then your ns2 is installed in the wrong folder. 
You must re-install ns2. Otherwise your updates in the files won't take effect. 
tcl files won't cause any problems. 
**But modifying internal .cc files like tcp.cc, tcp_reno.cc will not take effect**